# What is a good reference for basic shape detection algorithms

Tags: reference-request, algorithms

I've been doing research for a presentation on computer vision, and right now I'm specifically researching shape detection. Since this is a math course and not a programming course, I'm only concerned with the math behind it. In my research so far I've found an impressive variety of algorithms, but they all seem to be very advanced. I'm looking for something a little more basic, and my Google skills don't seem to be up to the task. Since the presentation is supposed to be around 15 slides, and many other computer vision topics are going to be discussed in addition to shape detection, I need to find something fairly short and concise. I understand this is a challenge since the topic is pretty complex, but I'm sure there's something that I can cram in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this freely available computer vision book:
[here](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf)

Comment: Wow... that's... a lot of information. It's an incredible resource if I want to learn everything about computer vision, but it's far more than I need for 15 PowerPoint slides. For the time being it does seem to be the best resource to pull from, though, since all of the information is sure to match up being written by a single author.